# Error connecting JMS to glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, jms

When I am trying to get a `DomainRoot` using the following:

```
final TLSParams tlsParams = new TLSParams( TrustAnyTrustManager.getInstanceArray(), null );
        final AppserverConnectionSource conn 
            = new AppserverConnectionSource(
                    AppserverConnectionSource.PROTOCOL_RMI, 
                        "localhost", 4848, "admin",
                            "adminadmin", tlsParams, null);
DomainRoot domainRoot = conn.getDomainRoot();
```

I get the following exceptions:

> ProxyFactory.getInstance: Failure trying to create a new ProxyFactory:
>   java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub:
>   javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is
>   java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection
>   establishment; nested exception is:

Anyone can help? Thanks.

Comment: Can you add more information about your OS, the versions of the software etc.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I am using win7, glassfish3, the jar files are from jdk1.4. Are these enough?

Comment: no problem, you are just starting out here. But it makes it a lot easier for people to answer well structured questions that provide all the necessary details. Essentially make it as easy as possible for people to contribute.